# group disappears while being dragged react-konva

Tags: events, canvas, drag-and-drop, react-konva, konva

currently working on a react-konva project with type script, trying to drag a group (it has a text and a rect shaped container..) , I created some functions for onDragMove,End and start , but whenever I start to drag the Item it dissappears, worked when I only dragged a text

tried to change parametesrs, put any parameters , change the values

the code for the dnd:

```
const handleDragStart = (draggedItem: KonvaEventObject<DragEvent>) => {
      if (draggedItem.target.isDragging() === true) {
        setStartingX(() => draggedItem.evt.clientX);
        setStartingY(() => draggedItem.evt.clientY);
      }

      draggedItem.target.scaleX(1.5);
      draggedItem.target.scaleY(1.5);
    };

    const handleDragMove = (draggedItem: KonvaEventObject<DragEvent>) => {
      const x = draggedItem.evt.clientX;
      const y = draggedItem.evt.clientY;

      if (x < 0) {
        draggedItem.target.absolutePosition({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else if (y > height - 50) {
        draggedItem.target.absolutePosition({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else if (y < 0) {
        draggedItem.target.absolutePosition({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else if (x > width - 200) {
        draggedItem.target.absolutePosition({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else {
        draggedItem.target.absolutePosition({
          x: Math.round(x / blockSnapWidthSize) * blockSnapWidthSize,
          y: Math.round(y / blockSnapHeightSize) * blockSnapHeightSize,
        });
      }

      draggedItem.target.scaleX(1.5);
      draggedItem.target.scaleY(1.5);
    };

    const handleDragEnd = (draggedItem: KonvaEventObject<DragEvent>) => {
      const x = draggedItem.evt.clientX;
      const y = draggedItem.evt.clientY;

      if (x < 0) {
        draggedItem.target.position({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else if (y > height - 50) {
        draggedItem.target.position({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else if (y < 0) {
        draggedItem.target.position({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else if (x > width - 200) {
        draggedItem.target.position({
          x: startingX,
          y: startingY,
        });
      } else {
        draggedItem.target.position({
          x: Math.round(x / blockSnapWidthSize) * blockSnapWidthSize,
          y: Math.round(y / blockSnapHeightSize) * blockSnapHeightSize,
        });
      }

      draggedItem.target.scaleX(1);
      draggedItem.target.scaleY(1);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use `draggedItem.evt.clientX`. `evt.clientX` is referencing to a native event on the position of the mouse relative to the page. That position may be very far from coordinates of the node, relative to konva stage.

It may be better to use konva methods to get positions, such as:

```js
const handleDragMove = (event: KonvaEventObject<DragEvent>) => {
  const node = event.target;
  const pos = node.position();
  const absPos = node.absolutePosition();
  // reset of your code
};
```

Comment: I've changed as you said and thank you for brighting my eyes for better ways of development (: , but sadly it didn't solve my issue and it still dissappaers....

Comment: @ohadlazar then make a clear online demo that shows the issue